# Flutter Webview onBackPressed Handle History

Tags: flutter, dart

> how can handle onbackPressed from a device, not an icon to back to previous
> page in webview if founded history in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to veto the usual behaviour of back button pressed. For eg let's say if you want to show a dialog warning the user if he/she really wants to exit, we can

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => showDialog( // Handle your logic here
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
            AlertDialog(title: Text('Do you want to quit?'), actions: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true)),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('No'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
            ])),
    child: Container(
      child: // Widget tree
    ))
```

Comment: I don't need to quit the app, I need to back to previous page in webview if found.

Comment: Please provide more context in the question you have asked, I'm unable to exactly get your question